# Running a Windows Application on a Mac

Tags: windows, mac, compatibility, cross-platform

I just did a presentation to a client of mine of a commercial Windows application I just made available. The problem is that this client just has Mac machines. I don’t know the Mac OS version.

So how can I run this program on a Mac?

The application is created in DELPHI 2007 Win32.

What solutions do I have available?

Comment: Why would you pick up a client that only uses Macs if you write Windows software?

Answer (score 4):

As Brian said, VirtualBox or VMWare should work, if you want to install a Windows VM on the client's machine.  Parallels is also popular on the mac and there's a slight chance the client may have it already.

Another option would be to use a remote tool such as gotomypc to connect to a windows machine running the software.

Comment: Virtualbox and VMWare are functional options, but he must consider licensing as well, and those require that there is licensed copy of Windows, which would increase the cost of his software per client a lot.

Comment: That's true.  For a demo I'd probably just connect from the mac to a Windows machine with GotoMyPC or Remote Desktop or something.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to do this natively if possible. Delphi will compile for OS X in the form of Free Pascal, but you must make some changes to the code for it to do so. For visual elements, you can use the open source free pascal implementation [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org).

This option will require some work and testing on an OS X machine, but so will configuration of WINE at install or installation of a VM to get the software running. Native binaries are much easier to troubleshoot as there is less involved in the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle VirtualBox and VMWare fusion are two options.

Answer (score 1):

Wine websites [says](http://wiki.winehq.org/MacOSX) it supports MacOS X. Maybe you can redistribute your application bundled with Wine.

Answer (score 1):

Gang, don't forget about using [codeweavers](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover/)  with this baby!